# Divs laid out side by side with inline-block change layout when child elements added

Tags: html, css

My goal is to create a list of divs, that lay out side by side, with a fixed width and height, some containing a bit of text and some not.

To achieve this I've used code similar to the following:

```
<div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card">
        <div>Testing 123</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card"></div>
</div>

.card {
    background-color: red;
    margin-left: 15px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The outcome I'm seeing is that when a child div is added to my cards, they bump down as if they had a large top margin. What I'd expect to see is all 3 divs laid out exactly next to each other.

Why is this happening, and what can I do to prevent it? Thanks for any information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
    .wrapper {
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .card {
      background-color: red;
      margin-left: 15px;
      width: 100px;
      height: 50px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
Try wrapping the 3 divs in a `flexbox`.

    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card">
        <div>Testing 123</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This works great, thanks! However I'm still curious why its necessary. Is div layout without flex just broken? Or is there something I don't understand about how inline-block divs are meant to layout?

Comment: The `vertical-align` on `.card` is set to `baseline`, as it's the default. Set it to `vertical-align: top;` instead of using flex and you'll see them align.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex-wrap property.

```css
 
    .card {
        background-color: red;
        margin-left: 15px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 50px;
        display: inline-block;
        
    }
    
    #dom{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;}
```

```html
 
    <div id="dom">
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card">
            <div>Testing 123</div>
        </div>
        <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This works great, thanks! However I'm still curious why its necessary. Is div layout without flex just broken? Or is there something I don't understand about how inline-block divs are meant to layout?